# First and second homotopy groups of a connected Lie group

Tags: lie-groups

I try to understand why for a connected Lie group $G$ the first fundamental group $\pi_1(G)$ is **abelian**, and mainly why the second fundamental group is **trivial** $\pi_2(G)=0$?

Thanks for anyone who give me references for a 'simple proof' of these results

Answer (score 8):

Some references:

- [This MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35868/fundamental-group-of-lie-groups) describes the Eckmann-Hilton argument.
- [Here's a blog post](http://hilbertthm90.wordpress.com/2010/09/08/lie-groups-have-abelian-fundamental-group/) about abelian $\pi_1$.
- [This other MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8957/homotopy-groups-of-lie-groups) has answers concerning the nullity of the second fundamental group.

Comment: Many thanks Willie, for the nice links. For $\pi_2(G)=0$ I guess there is no simple proof! :((