# Natural numbers $n$ for which $\pi_n(G)=0$ for all Lie groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homotopy-theory

It is a [classical theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61386/first-and-second-homotopy-groups-of-a-connected-lie-group) that $\pi_2(G)$ is trivial for all Lie group $G$.

Is $n=2$ the only  natural number with the  property that $\pi_n(G)$ is  trivial for  every Lie group $G$?

Comment: $S^3$ is a Lie group. Are there any $n\ge3$ for which $\pi_n(S^3)=0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  For all $n>2$, $\pi_n(S^3)$ is nontrivial: see https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.00952.

Or, using just results from the 1950s, by Bott periodicity, $\pi_n(U(m))\cong\mathbb{Z}$ if $n$ is odd and $m$ is sufficiently large.  Even $n>2$ are handled by the fact that $\pi_{2m}(U(m))\cong\mathbb{Z}/(m!)$ for all $m$.